# ¿Cómo imprimir números repetidos de un array?

Tags: java, array

Estamos en una encrucijada, no tenemos una idea respecto a cómo podríamos mostrar la cantidad de veces que se repite un número en un `array` en el siguiente formato: En el `vector A`, el número **"+15+"** fue ingresado 3 veces y se encuentra en la posición **1, 2 y 5**. Y que dependiendo de las veces que se repita (en caso de ser más) se muestren las posiciones asociadas a esa igualdad y la cantidad de veces. Espero haber sido claro. Adjunto el código base con el estamos intentando encontrar alguna solución.

```
  int arreglo[] = new int[5];
  int veces = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("Ingrese la posición "+(i+1)+": ");
      arreglo[i] = leer();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length-1; i++) {
      for (int j = i+1; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
        if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[j]) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta podría ser la solución a tu problema, basado en el código que estas usando, también se imprimen los datos procesados, acoplalo a lo que necesites:

```
  int MAXIMO = 5;
  int arreglo[] = new int[MAXIMO];
  int[] repeticiones[] = new int[MAXIMO][MAXIMO];
  int veces = 0;
  int arregloSecundarioPosicion = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("Ingrese la posición "+(i+1)+": ");
      arreglo[i] = leer();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    arregloSecundarioPosicion = 0;
    for (int j = i+1; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
        if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[j]) {
              repeticiones[i][arregloSecundarioPosicion++] = j;
            }
        }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println("Repeticiones: "+repeticiones[i].length);
    System.out.println("Posiciones: ");
    for (int j = i; j < repeticiones[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(repeticiones[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
1600000000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
000000000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
00000000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
0000000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
000000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
00000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
0000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
000Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
00Repeticiones: 10
Posiciones: 
0

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta pero algo así es que lo forma ese código en conjunto al resto del mío.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar hacerlo de esta manera para que haya menos problemas y se asemeje más a lo que quieres

```
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
int conteo = 0;
String cadena = "";
      for (int j = i+1; j < (arreglo.length-1); j++) {
        if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[j]) {
             conteo++;
             cadena += "Entró la posición " + j + "\n";

            }

        }
System.out.prinln("Registros del numero " + arreglo[i] + "\n" + cadena);
    }
```

El va a entrar en cada numero y va a decir sí el numero se repite o no, y el conteo se reinicia cada vez que cambia de numero, diciéndote, cuántas veces se repite cada numero del arreglo, alguna duda me comentas

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero ya había intentado esa forma y no consigo llegar a lo que necesito. Más que nada necesito mostrar más de 2 posiciones en el caso de que estas coincidan con el mismo valor. Por ejemplo, la posición 1, 2 y 5 del arreglo guardan el número 3. Necesito mostrar en un sout esas posiciones.

Comment: @Luis Pues tomando en cuenta eso pues haces lo mismo, en una `String cadena = " "` puedes guardar cada vez que se entra en la condición el arreglo por ejemplo, `cadena += "Entró la posición" + j ` y así, lo edito para que te hagas una idea

Comment: He intentado con eso pero no he logrado llegar a nada. Supongo que mi razonamiento no logra conectar las ideas.

De todas formas agradezco vuestra ayuda a todos.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te sale @Luis?

Answer (score 0):

**Imprimir números repetidos en un arreglo**

Después de obtener el array de enteros:

```
int arreglo[] = new int[5];
  int veces = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("Ingrese la posición "+(i+1)+": ");
      arreglo[i] = leer();
  }
```

te sugiero usar el siguiente método que determinará los elementos en el array que se encuentran repetidos:

```
public void imprimeNumerosRepetido(int arreglo[]){
    int maxValue = 1000; //El mayor valor es 1000, este valor puede ser cambiado;
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = arreglo[i];
    }
    //Arreglo donde se almacenaran los valores repetidos en el array inicial.
    int elementosRepetidos[] = new int[maxValue + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        elementosRepetidos[arreglo[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++) { //Imprime elementos que se repiten mas de 1 ocasión
        if (elementosRepetidos[i] > 1)
            System.out.println("Se repite " + elementosRepetidos[i] + " veces el numero: " + i);
    }

}
```

De acuerdo a lo que comentas en tu pregunta,

> En el vector A, el número "+15+" fue ingresado 3 veces y se encuentra
> en la posición 1, 2 y 5.

al obtener el arreglo:

```
   int arreglo[]  = {15,15,2,3,15};
```

y llamar el método:

```
imprimeNumerosRepetido(arreglo);
```

obtendrás como salida:

> Se repite 3 veces el numero: 15